# Will paper heated in outer space just evaporate?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, material-science, phase-transition, physical-chemistry

If a piece of paper is heated in outer space (or in a vacuum chamber), what will I see? Will it just evaporate? I can't imagine that it first melts...

Comment: I would think it would vapourize since I'm pretty sure paper flat out doesn't melt.

Comment: I think a chemist would be able to give you a better answer, but it's probably going to be pyrolysed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrolysis

Comment: I don't think it'll evaporate completely. Granted, for combustion (in air) there must be some volatile substance emitted to feed the flame, but after a paper is burnt, there does remain solid substance: ash. I suppose something similar would remain after heating without air, just maybe not oxidized as ash is.

Comment: I agree with @Vercassivelaunos .  Organic compounds contain both carbon and oxygen, so quite possibly large-ish molecules will break down into smaller "oxidized" molecules like  CO2 , or even (saying this hopefully from a what-if.xkcd point of view) release a littleO2 which promptly 'burns' other local compounds in the paper.

Answer (score 2):

As @Vercassivelaunos notes, the paper [pyrolyzes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrolysis) or thermally decomposes. As the heating process begins, all condensed matter is sublimating very slowly into the vacuum according to its corresponding [vapor pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapor_pressure). Any volatile adsorbed substances, such as water, evaporates quickly (by definition of volatile), termed [outgassing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outgassing).

The stability of phases and compounds is defined by the [Gibbs free energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy). Broadly, Nature prefers both strong bonding (low enthalpy) and many possibilities (high entropy). The Gibbs free energy represents both, and the temperature coefficient of the entropy term means that the higher-entropy phase or product is always favored at higher temperature. Consequently, the cellulose in the paper, which was stable at room temperature, decomposes at high temperature into smaller units, including gases, because of the higher entropy of the gas phase. H<sub>2</sub>, CO<sub>2</sub>,
CO, CH<sub>4</sub>, C<sub>2</sub>H<sub>6</sub>, C<sub>2</sub>H<sub>4</sub>, and larger gaseous organics disperse into the void. The remaining elemental solid ash ultimately sublimates with exponentially increasing speed upon continued heating.

Answer (score 1):

Charcoal is the product of heating wood in the absence of oxygen. I would expect paper to become a sheet of charcoal. This is mostly carbon, not ash.

Of course, at high temperature the carbon will evaporate, leaving ash, and at higher temperature that will also.